# wp_count_posts, wp_count_terms and wp_count_comments for specific user?

Tags: widgets, users, dashboard, count

Is there a way for the functions `wp_count_posts`, `wp_count_terms` and `wp_count_comments` to return their results only for a specific user, possibly by using a user's `ID`?

I'm making a custom "Right Now" dashboard widget for a custom post type and I need it to show data for the current user only, not for the whole site.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**: In response to @kaiser 's comment below, I did the following, but nothing's happening - the results are the same as when the filter is out (which should not be the case - checked that this user has a different number of published `employee` post types). It seems that the code inside my function is not even being called at all coz it's not outputting the test `echo` statement inside it:

```
<?php

// employer right now widget
wp_add_dashboard_widget('dashboard_right_now', __('Right Now'), 'employer_dashboard_right_now');
function limit_to_current_user( $where ) {
    global $wpdb, $current_user;
    $current_user_ID = (int) $current_user->ID;

    $new_where = $wpdb->prepare( 
        $where . " AND post_author = %s "
        ,$current_user_ID );

    var_dump($new_where); // not dumping anything, not even string(0) "" and no errors reported whatsoever, even in php_error_log

    return $new_where;
}
function employer_dashboard_right_now() {

    // modify query to limit to current user
    add_filter('posts_where', 'limit_to_current_user');
    // execute queries
    $num_employees = wp_count_posts('employee');
    $num_comm = wp_count_comments();
    // remove filter
    remove_filter('posts_where', 'limit_to_current_user');

    // more code here...

}

?>
```

Comment: Intercept the query inside the `posts_where` filter.

Comment: kewl, i'll look that up and ask you if i can't make it work. thanks!

Comment: There're plenty of examples here on the page. Just take care that you add your custom filter _right before_ you make that call and remove it _right after_ you made it, to avoid intercepting other queries.

Comment: kk, workin on it..

Comment: @kaiser mind takin' a look the question edit? thanks so much :D

Comment: `function` inside a `function` - you should really move that one out. Also: Use `$wpdb->prepare()`. Documented in codex and works like `sprintf()`. As I said: Look at the examples, search my answers, you'll find plenty of "Do it this or that way". Further: `php_error`, `WP_DEBUG` and dump your strings before using it. You're not trying to guess the outcoming, aren't you?

Comment: ehm.... nope, yeap, ... what?

Comment: i updated the edit. still nothing happening - `where` clause not being modified, no dumps, no errors whatsoever. i even tried `$num_employees = wp_count_posts('employee', array( 'suppress_filters' => FALSE));` and still nothing. any idea? :/

Comment: Well done so far. Inside the where-filter-cb-fn, there's something pretty strange. From looking at your code, there _should_ be a dump. What do you currently get from the `var_dump`? Something like an empty string?

Comment: ikr? unfortunately, i get nothing. if i `echo` something right before and after the `var_dump` line nothing gets `echo`'d as well.. afaik an empty string should dump `string(0) ""`, but in this case absolutely nothing gets dumped, and the query isn't modified, either.. it's like `var_dump` isn't even being executed at all, and perhaps the whole filter. hmm.. you think it has something to do with `suppress_filters`? though i've had no luck at that end, either.. or probably this function just ain't `hook`able.. what do you think?

Comment: Very strange... Yes, it _could_ be something with `suppress_filters`. You could also try the `apply_filters( 'query', $query );` filter.

Comment: aaiyt.. will give y'all a heads up on monday.. i'll be away for the weekend, say whutt?? thanks @kaiser really 'preciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own custom code for `wp_count_posts()` and `wp_count_comments()` to generate the counts from scratch (through custom wp queries) based on their original code (`wp_count_posts()` is in `wp-includes/post.php` and `wp_count_comments()` is in `wp-includes/comment.php`). Thanks @kaiser for the excellent effort.

Comment: Could you please provide the functions (or at least specify the main details of them)? I am trying to figure out how to calculate the number of drafts and waiting comments for a specified blog (`$user_blog->userblog_id`) but can only get the counts for the current blog. What you did is similar, so hopefully it can lead me in the right direction.